# React - event for action result received

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to have an event that will trigger when I receive a certain data from the server-side.

I tried using `componentWillReceiveProps` but if the server returns the same data this event will not be hit. What event can I use, I want to start the event even if the data received is the same.

My reducer:

```
import * as constActions from './remediationConstActions';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function alertsPageReducer(state=initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case constActions.SEND_TO_SOC_SUCCESS:
        {
            return Object.assign({}, state, 
                {
                remediationResult:
                    action.remediationResult
                });
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

In my component:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        remediationResult: state.remediation.remediationResult
    }        
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('remediationDidReceiveResult:' + this.nextProps.remediationDidReceiveResult);        
}
```

Whats the solution?

Comment: This might be a silly question I'm about to ask but why do you need to re-render the component if nothing has changed? Does it include a timestamp? In that case just pass the timestamp as a prop?

Comment: @ivarni Its a popup, and even if the user clicks on the same button twice the result is the same. But i do want to know that the result came before i show the popup. I am not 100% sure i structured it properly, but it works fine other than this issue

Comment: @ivarni lets say I add the timestamp, Now i have another issue, in the event I want to know where i came from, how can i know that? I want to know what action changed the props

Comment: The whole point of flux-like architectures are to isolate your component from knowing about those things, so I think it will be difficult to achieve in any other way than putting it in state. Someone might come along with a solution, but I've no idea :)

Comment: @ivarni Timestamp and state solved it, but it feels really dirty

Comment: I know what you feel like, I just ended up putting form input state into a redux-store after months of fighting against the idea. It's how the framework is designed to work though, and fighting against it would probably lead you down an even dirtier path if that's any consolation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your redux reducer a counter and increment it every time when reducer called.

```
return {
  ...state,
  remediationResult: action.remediationResult,
  version: state.version + 1 }
```

So if you will connect this counter to a prop, in `componentWillReceiveProps` you could compare your `version` numbers and call a handler if it changes.